# pygame audio playback speed

Tags: python, pygame

quick question.

I'm running pygame under linux just to play some audio files.
I've got some .wav files and I'm having problems playing them back at the right speed.

```
import pygame.mixer, sys, time

#plays too fast
pygame.mixer.init(44100)
pygame.mixer.music.load(sys.argv[1])
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
pygame.mixer.quit()

#plays too slow
pygame.mixer.init(22100)
pygame.mixer.music.load(sys.argv[1])
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
pygame.mixer.quit()
```

I've ggogle code searched some stuff but everybody seems to be fine calling the init function with its default parameters. Can others try running this script and seeing if they get the same behavior or not? Does anybody know how to speed it up? Or adjust the speed for each file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...
There is a wave module http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html and it can read the sample rate for wav files.

Answer (score 5):

I had some mp3 audio tracks playing back slowed down. I updated the mixer frequency to be based on the mp3 sample rate using [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp3.html) like so:

```
import pygame, mutagen.mp3

song_file = "your_music.mp3"

mp3 = mutagen.mp3.MP3(song_file)
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=mp3.info.sample_rate)

pygame.mixer.music.load(song_file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

And it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

To improve [Chris H answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2164987/920031). Here is a example of how to use the `wave` library.

```
import wave
import pygame

file_path = '/path/to/sound.wav'
file_wav = wave.open(file_path)
frequency = file_wav.getframerate()
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=frequency)
pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Remember that if you want to change `frequency` or any other parameter used in `pygame.mixer.init` you must call `pygame.mixer.quit` first. [Pygame documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init)

Answer (score 3):

Open your audio file in a free audio tool like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net).  It will tell you the sampling rate of your media.  It will also allow you to convert to a different sampling rate so all your sounds can be the same.

Comment: Not neccesarily.  I'm sure you could figure out some way to calculate the sample rate of the input media in Python and then resample the media appropriately.  This would allow you to handle foreign media supplied by your users properly.  However, pygame must playback media at a consistent rate and that rate must match the sampling rate of the media itself.  There is no way around that fact.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ogg Vorbis (.ogg) encoding, the same problem of stuttering audio happens. You'll have to read the frequency of what you're trying to play before initializing the mixer object.

Here's how to play .ogg audio with appropriate frequency using pygame.

```
from pyogg import VorbisFile
from pygame import mixer

# path to your audio
path = "./file.ogg"
# an object representing the audio, see https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyOgg
sound = VorbisFile(path)
# pull the frequency out of the Vorbis abstraction
frequency = sound.frequency
# initialize the mixer
mixer.init(frequency=frequency)
# add the audio to the mixer's music channel
mixer.music.load(path)
# mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
# mixer.music.fadeout(15)
# play
mixer.music.play()
```